# Using Force instead of torque to calculate angular acceleration

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Suppose we have a solid filled cone with small oscillations occurring about its apex. We can find its equation of motion in $\theta$ with the M.O.I by $I\frac{dw}{dt} = -mgL\sin\theta$. Where L is the distance to the centre of mass from the apex and gravity provides net torque about the centre of mass (by definition). But why can we not use equate the tangential component of gravity with the acceleration of the centre of mass instead, like it has been shown with a pendulum bob?

I'm guessing it's to do with the fact that the tangential forces on the bob are known to be purely due to gravity because tension is radial, however this isn't the case with a cone?

Comment: Who says that you cannot use the same method for the cone as for the pendulum?

Comment: i didn't mean to imply that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the hinge in apex produces a force to make the apex stay at rest, that force has horizontal and vertical components.